# The "ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X | ssh-keygen -lf -" command does not work in macOS "El Capitan"

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

In Linux and (Windows through gitbash) if is executed the command:

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

Works as expected, but in macOS (El Capitan) arises

```
-: No such file or directory
# 192.168.1.X SSH-2.0-OpenSSH .....
# 192.168.1.X SSH-2.0-OpenSSH .....
# 192.168.1.X SSH-2.0-OpenSSH .....
```

How fix this?

**Note** The `bash` version in my macOS is *3.2.57(1)-release* and if is executed `ssh -V` it returns *OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8*

Comment: In macOS Monterey the command above works, so it seems the Openssh version included with El Capitan doesn't support reading the key file from standard input (note that Apple has its own fork of openssh, see https://opensource.apple.com/releases/). As a workaround, you could use process substitution as follows `ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X)`. Could you try it and report back?

Comment: Thanks for the support - when is executed the suggested command - the latest line is `/dev/fd/63 is not a public key file` - I added the SSH version info in the post too

Comment: Thank you for testing, too bad it didn't work. You will have to save the key file first and then pass it to `ssh-keygen`, for example: `ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X > /tmp/keyfile; ssh-keygen -lf /tmp/keyfile; rm /tmp/keyfile`. You could save that command as a shell function to speed up the process (if you need help with that, let me know and I'll post an answer).

Comment: Your command works. Just being curious why was used `;` over `&&`?

Comment: I'm glad it works. I prefer to use `;` because `cmdA && cmdB` describes a conditional relationship, that is, `cmdA` is executed only if `cmdB` was successful, which could prevent that the temporary file gets deleted in the last step if an error occurs. `;`, on the other side, is just a separator so that all commands are executed, so that I know the temporary file will always be deleted. Should I post an answer, or do you prefer to do it?

Comment: Pls, post your answer - your solution works and of course is valid. So it deserve be marked as an answer. Consider to indicate the `;` `&` difference

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've added an answer with the **one-liner** above and also with a **shell function**, which may be more convenient to use. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Openssh version included with El Capitan **doesn't support reading the key file from standard input** and [according to your tests](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449144/the-ssh-keyscan-192-168-1-x-ssh-keygen-lf-command-does-not-work-in-macos#comment650095_449144), **doesn't suport [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)** (`ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X)` either.

That means that you will have to save the key file first and then pass it to `ssh-keygen`.

You can use:

- a **function** (change `skg` to a name of your liking):

  ```
  function skg() {
      if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
          echo "$FUNCNAME: Specify an IP address or host name to read an SSH key from";
          return 1;
      else
          ip_address=$1;
      fi;
      tmp_file=$(mktemp);
      ssh-keyscan $ip_address > $tmp_file;
      ssh-keygen -lf $tmp_file
      rm $tmp_file
  }
  ```

  where:

  - `mktemp` is a command that creates a temporary file with a unique name that is only readable by you.
  - `$FUNCNAME` is a shell variable that returns the function name

  Add the function to your `.bashrc` file, open a Terminal window and execute it as follows:

  `skg 192.168.1.X`
- a **one-line**r:

  `ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X > /tmp/keyfile; ssh-keygen -lf /tmp/keyfile; rm /tmp/keyfile`

  (Note that I use `;` to separate commands instead of `&&` because the latter is a *conditional operator*, that is, in a construct like this: `commandA && commandB`, `commandB` will only be executed if `commandA` is successful, which could prevent that the temporary file gets deleted in the last step if an error occurs. `;`, on the other hand, is just a separator so that all commands are executed, so the temporary file will always be deleted.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra function code - BTW the correct order is _commandB is only executed if commandA was successful_ - I suggested the edition